# GeForce 970GTX - why are heatpipes so hot in idle?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I recently bought a nice MSI GeForce 970GTX, but I wonder why although CPUID HWMonitor says TMPIN0 is just 58°C I can barely touch the heatpipes on the card because they are so hot it would make burn marks on my fingers after two seconds. I am not playing any game so the GPU is idling at around 10%. Is this temperature reading wrong and there is another value which HWMonitor does not show? Or is it possible that heatpipes are somehow much hotter then the GPU chip?

Comment: What's the temperature in your room? Is your GPU getting adequate airflow?

Answer (score 0):

I can not fully answer your question but I have a GTX970 from Gigabyte and have to say that 58°C seems to be extremely high for idle.

On idle I ususally have around 30°C (30% fan utilization). I just ran a game (Witcher 3, max details) to check temperatures and I have max 55 °C (55% fan utilization).

So there seems to be something wrong with your GPU/cooling.

Comment: MSI uses [Zero Frozer](https://www.msi.com/Graphics-card/GTX-970-GAMING-4G.html#hero-overview) so the GPU does not utilize any fans until it reaches 60°C. That's why the card gets hotter in idle situations than yours. I don't think there's something wrong with his card or cooler ;)

Comment: I know that GPUs don't generally have any problems running on around 90°C. They are built for it. 30°C is really no reason for fans to spin :)